# Addition doesn't work properly with some numbers in TikZ/PGF

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfmath

I have a problem with very simple calculations in TikZ/PGF. After displaying many calculations properly I encountered the problem, that pgfmathadd returns 5.40001, if i want to add 1.6 and 3.8, witch i thought is not a real problem. If i add 0.1 in one number and -0.1 to the other, the problem vanishes. I'm confused, no expert in PGF or TikZ and too concerned to use it again, if i can't be sure whether the calculations are precise enough or not. I also have no clue what's so special in 1.6 and 3.8.

Here's a basic code, witch returns the following answers after compilation. 
a) 3,8 + 1,6 = 5.40001 b) 3,6 + 1,8 = 5.40001 c) 3,7 + 1,6 = 5.3 d) 3,7 + 1,5 = 5.4
e) 3,8 + 1,6 = 5.4 f) 3,8 + 1,6 = 5.40001 g) 3,8 + 1,6 = 5.40001 h) 3,8 + 1,6 = 5.40001

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath} % Erweiterter Formelsatz - Hauptpaket!
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{xalignat*}{4}
 &a)\,\,3,8+1,6=\pgfmathadd{3.8}{1.6}\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed, precision=6]\pgfmathresult &  
 &b)\,\,3,6+1,8=\pgfmathadd{3.6}{1.8}\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed, precision=6]\pgfmathresult   &
 &c)\,\, 3,7+1,6=\pgfmathadd{3.7}{1.6}\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed, precision=6]\pgfmathresult & 
 &d)\,\,3,7+1,5=\pgfmathadd{3.9}{1.5}\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed, precision=6]\pgfmathresult\\
 &e)\,\,3,8+1,6=\pgfmathadd{3.8}{1.6}\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed, precision=4]\pgfmathresult &  
 &f)\,\,3,8+1,6=\pgfmathadd{3.8}{1.6}\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed, precision=5]\pgfmathresult &
 &g)\,\,3,8+1,6=\pgfmathadd{3.8}{1.6}\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed, precision=6]\pgfmathresult &
 &h)\,\,3,8+1,6=\pgfmathadd{3.8}{1.6}\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed, precision=7]\pgfmathresult 
\end{xalignat*}
\end{document}
```

I hope someone could help me out, because it would make work much easier. I use it for big amounts of calculations, which I don't want to do myself. Sorry for the crude english.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). Note that you don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post.

Comment: Essentially this is happening: `\dimen0=1.6pt \dimen1=3.8pt \advance\dimen0 by\dimen1 \the\dimen0`.

Comment: The solution by egreg works, but now i'm ensountering an new problem, and i'm not alone with it. Using the fpu-library changes the number format, and some tikz-functions don't work properly after that. I tried to switch fpu off an on again, witch someone mentioned in other posts, but i couldn't get it work. Maybe i'm too dumb to read manuals, but this freaks me out. I want this to work properly :"\marginpar{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{\node[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=2pt] (char) {\textcolor{red}{1}};}}" Any suggestions?

Comment: I fixed it myself. One has to switch fpu-library off and on outside the marginpar-environment with \pgfkeys{pgf/fpu=false}. I tried to switch it off inside, witch doesn't work. I hope that's it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use the `fpu` library, if you plan to do “exact” computations. Otherwise PGF uses TeX's arithmetic which is not accurate enough.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepgflibrary{fpu}
\pgfkeys{pgf/fpu}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{*{4}{r@{\enspace}>{$}l<{$}}}
a) & 3.8+1.6=\pgfmathadd{3.8}{1.6}\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed, precision=6]\pgfmathresult &
b) & 3.6+1.8=\pgfmathadd{3.6}{1.8}\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed, precision=6]\pgfmathresult &
c) & 3.7+1.6=\pgfmathadd{3.7}{1.6}\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed, precision=6]\pgfmathresult &
d) & 3.7+1.5=\pgfmathadd{3.9}{1.5}\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed, precision=6]\pgfmathresult\\
e) & 3.8+1.6=\pgfmathadd{3.8}{1.6}\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed, precision=4]\pgfmathresult &
f) & 3.8+1.6=\pgfmathadd{3.8}{1.6}\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed, precision=5]\pgfmathresult &
g) & 3.8+1.6=\pgfmathadd{3.8}{1.6}\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed, precision=6]\pgfmathresult &
h) & 3.8+1.6=\pgfmathadd{3.8}{1.6}\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed, precision=7]\pgfmathresult
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can use the `fp` library in `expl3`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
% #1 = precision (with truncation), optional (default 0)
% #2 = expression
\NewDocumentCommand{\printexpr}{O{0}m}
 {
  %\fp_to_decimal:n { round0 ( #2, #1 ) } % old syntax
  \fp_to_decimal:n { trunc ( #2, #1 ) }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{*{4}{r@{\enspace}>{$}l<{$}}}
a) & 3.8+1.6=\printexpr[1]{3.8+1.6} &
b) & 3.6+1.8=\printexpr[2]{3.6+1.8} &
c) & 3.7+1.6=\printexpr[2]{3.7+1.6} &
d) & 3.7+1.5=\printexpr[3]{3.7+1.5} \\
e) & 3.8+1.6=\printexpr[4]{3.8+1.6} &
f) & 3.8+1.6=\printexpr[5]{3.8+1.6} &
g) & 3.8+1.6=\printexpr[6]{3.8+1.6} &
h) & 3.8+1.6=\printexpr[7]{3.8+1.6}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

**Note:** as of the December 2013 update to the `expl3` suite, the keywords `round-`, `round+` and `round0` in the syntax for fixed point expression evaluation have been changed to

> `floor` (was `round-`)
>    `ceil` (was `round+`)
>    `trunc` (was `round0`)

Comment: That does the trick, thanks. I already tried to use that library before i posted the question, but obviously i tried it the wrong way. This answer showed me the right way, and with this additions to the preamble "\pgfqkeys{/pgf/number format}{fixed ,precision=6,1000 sep={\,},use comma}" i got back my german style, witch i didn't mention in the post. Thanks again for the fast and proper anwer. :-)